# How to read/decode/parse HTTP/2.0 capture decrypted by Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, decryption

I thought Wireshark successfully decrypted an encrypted HTTP/2.0 connection once it was pointed to pre-master secrets from Firefox after setting SSLKEYLOGFILE.

It shows the header when following the stream:

```
PRI * HTTP/2.0

SM
```

But then garbled text follows, like some additional decoding is required. A small example:

```
vR.Q&4n
```

This is with more than one domain too. What else should I do to fix this?

Comment: HTTP/2 Headers are compressed per RFC7541

Comment: `Wireshark 2.4 - header decompression support now requires external nghttp2 package (true for official Windows/macOS builds).` [Wireshark wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HTTP2)

I installed nghttp2, but I'm on Linux. No change.